# Como validar se uma frase que contém palavras com acento foi exibida na tela?

Tags: android, ruby

Estou utilizando o Calabash-Android para efetuar testes automatizados e desejo saber como posso validar se uma frase que contém palavras com acento foi exibida na tela.

---

**arquivo.feature**

```
# language: pt
# encoding: utf-8

Funcionalidade: Cálculo de triângulo

Cenário: Calculando um triângulo equilátero
    Dado que estou na tela do TrianguloApp
    Quando eu preencher o campo Lado 1 com "3"
        E eu preencher o campo Lado 2 com "3"
        E eu preencher o campo Lado 3 com "3"
        E eu clicar em Calcular
    Entao a mensagem "O triângulo é Equilátero" será exibida
```

---

**arquivo_steps.rb**

```
    Dado(/^que estou na tela do TrianguloApp$/) do
         element_exists("* text:'TrianguloApp'")
    end

    Quando(/^eu preencher o campo Lado 1 com "(.*?)"$/) do |lado1|
           enter_text "* id:'txtLado1'", "#{lado1}"
    end

    Quando(/^eu preencher o campo Lado 2 com "(.*?)"$/) do |lado2|
           enter_text "* id:'txtLado2'", "#{lado2}"
    end

    Quando(/^eu preencher o campo Lado 3 com "(.*?)"$/) do |lado3|
           enter_text "* id:'txtLado3'", "#{lado3}"
    end

    Quando(/^eu clicar em Calcular$/) do
           touch("* id:'btnCalcular'")
    end

    Entao(/^a mensagem "(.*?)" será exibida$/) do |mensagem|
          element_exists("* O triângulo é Equilátero")
    end
```

---

Esse é o resultado do teste.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro ocorreu porque estou tentando validar se a frase `O triângulo é Equilátero` foi exibida na tela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui validar a frase `O triângulo é Equilátero`

Eu mudei o comando `element_exists` para `macro %Q|I should see "#{text}"|`

Veja como ficou:

`Entao(/^a mensagem "(.*?)" será exibida$/) do |mensagem|
    macro %Q|I should see "#{mensagem}"|
end`

Fonte: http://testmunk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/steps.html